# What are the main purposes for joining pthreads in Linux/UNIX?

Tags: linux, multithreading, unix, pthreads

I'm a student and I'm going over threads right now, and despite reading TLPI very carefully, I still don't have a good understanding as to why one might join two pthreads.

From what I've gleaned, it can be used either as a way for one thread to pass a return value to another OR it can be used as a waiting mechanism between threads. That said, it's entirely possible that I've misunderstood the entire point. Would someone mind explaining it a bit for me?

Comment: Joining a non-detached thread is the only way to recover all the resources (notably its stack space) used...

Comment: The main reason is so that you can know when the thread is done (and collect any returned value if you're interested in that).  So, it's what you've gleaned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Threads are mainly used for parallel processing. **Joining/Exiting** threads means the work/purpose of the thread is fulfilled. When the purpose is fulfilled then the resources should be **freed and made available to other threads/processes**. Resources could be any of following:

1. Stack (as Basile Starynkevitch said)
2. Processor time
3. Opened files/Shared Memory/Any other resource locked/booked by the thread.

Joining threads can be done for just **shifting the control** also Or it might be done for **transferring values** as return values (as  Michael Burr said).